# No result is displayed when I include my commented lines

Tags: php, html, mysql

the code below works fine if I uncomment the commented lines, I'm really not sure as to why it is not displaying anything when I include the commented lines. Thank you for your time and assistance.

I need that certain piece of code to check every time a phone number is searched so that it will automatically update the table "Notes" to Expired to let me know that the registration has already expired.

```
<?php

include_once('assets/inc/db_login.inc');
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

if(empty($_POST["phone"])) {
  $unameErr = "Phone is required";
}
else {
  $phone = clean_input($_POST["phone"]);
}
}

$check = sql_entry($phone);

/* Functions */

function clean_input($login){

$login = trim($login);
$login = stripslashes($login);
$login = htmlspecialchars($login);

return $login;

}

function sql_entry($phone){

//do not touch anything beyond this part
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

//error catcher for connection failure
if($conn->connect_error){
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//clean themmmmmm!
$clean_phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $phone);

//prepare queries
$verification = "SELECT * FROM ".DB_TBL." WHERE phone = ".$clean_phone;
$verification_result = mysqli_query($conn,$verification); //run query to validate phone number

/*

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($verification_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$startdate = $row['register_date'];
$expire = strtotime($startdate. ' + 182 days');
$today = strtotime("today midnight");

if($today >= $expire){
$update = "UPDATE ".DB_TBL." SET notes='Expired' WHERE phone = ".$clean_phone;
$run_update = mysqli_query($conn,$update);
}

*/

return $verification_result;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> - | User Registration</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <center><br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table width="500", cellpadding=5 callspacing=5 border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Register Date</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Note</th>
    </tr>

    <?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($check, MYSQLI_ASSOC)): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rows['username']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['register_date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['phone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['points']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['notes']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: hello, it runs perfectly on mine, its just when i uncomment the block of code i've commented, it wont display any output anymore.

Commented: http://prntscr.com/cscsov
Uncommented: http://prntscr.com/cscsww

Note: I've already added the code you have provided, there are no error displays. It works as intended as long as I comment the block of code.

Comment: ok that's not no output, that's clearly some output

Comment: please type print_r($verification_result) befor and after the commented part, uncomment it and tell us the output.

Comment: Hello @someone, I've done what you've said and it looks as follows:

http://prntscr.com/csczd1

Output:

`mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 6 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 ) mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 6 [lengths] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 9 [2] => 10 [3] => 10 [4] => 3 [5] => 4 ) [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )`

Comment: @CyanHijirikawa Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewind result set so it could be iterated again or build data structure for both display and update with one iteration (actually you could update without pulling data from db - use conditions in query). Rewind would need less changes in the code - just add this at the end of commented part:

```
mysqli_data_seek($verification_result, 0);
```

Btw. Your `UPDATE` works with first returned row only, and later you try to iterate like there could be more results. If it was the case then (without rewind) you would update first and display rest of them.

Comment: This is better than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before the commented part:

```
$verification_result_clone = clone($verification_result);
```

and replace

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($verification_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

with

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($verification_result_clone, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

**UPDATE:**

I didn't know that `mysql_result` class is not cloneable. Sorry for that.

Well, I think you should run your query twice. Try this:

Replace

```
$verification_result_clone = clone($verification_result);
```

with

```
$verification_result_clone = mysqli_query($conn,$verification);
```

from my answer above. That should work now.

Comment: Hello @someone, I tried what you suggested and I got the following errors.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Trying to clone an uncloneable object of class mysqli_result in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\sql.php:49 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\sql.php(18): sql_entry('7083281100') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\sql.php on line 49`